# Create a document with multiple sections each containing a plot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, markdown, r-markdown

I have this dataframe

```
sales <-
  data.frame(
    "month" = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-01"), 
    "type" = c("us", "rest", "us", "rest"),
    "net_inc" = c(500, 600, 800, 900),
    stringsAsFactors = F
    )
```

I created even some graph from this data

```
ggplot(sales, aes(x=month, y=type, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

But now I'd like to prepare markdown document with separate graph for each month and I have no clue how to do it except manually filter each month and then create graph from this filtered data.

So my question is how to achieve from sales dataframe this:

1. Have subheaders in markdown (`## 2018-01`)
2. Create plot for each month in my df (please note that in my dataframe data starts from year 2000 to current date)

Comment: Please don’t cram a few tags into the title — after all, that‘s what the *tags* are for. Instead, use a self-contained sentence (fragment) as a title, to be complemented by tags.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do with the example and objective you have provided is the following. First we make a plot for each month:

```
plotlist <- split(sales, sales$month)
plotlist <- lapply(plotlist, function(df){
  ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = type, fill = type)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
})
```

Then make headers and chunks wherein you print each element of the plot list:

````
## Month 1

```{r}
print(plotlist[[1]])
```

## Month 2

```{r}
print(plotlist[[2]])
```
````

I don't know of any way to programmatically construct markdown documents (which doesn't mean it doesn't exist), so I can only help you thus far.

Alternatively, if you don't mind the output you could just do the following:

````
```{r}
print(plotlist)
```
````

Which will print in your output file as such:

[image]

And still keeps your plot with month information together.

Comment: No need for the `print(…)` around the plots. If anything I’d suggest writing `plot` instead of `print`, but neither is necessary.